# How to add data to Editor using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new to JS and try to add data to textarea.

Html textarea code:

```
<textarea class="wysihtml5 form-control" rows="6" name="notes" id="edit_notes" data-error-container="#editor1_error" required></textarea>
```

Ajax append data code:

```
success: function(data){
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('#edit_notes').setData(result[0].jobdescription);

      }
```

but this doesn't pass data to editor.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `setData` is not jquery method.

Comment: which jquery editor are you using?

Comment: You're probably thinking of `data`

Comment: I think it's a bootstrap editor not jquery.

Comment: @Clive - i just need to append 'jobdescription' into text editor.

Comment: Without knowing what library you're using, it's not possible to say

Answer (score 0):

Try with `val()`

```
 $('#edit_notes').val(result[0].jobdescription);
```

```js
$('textarea').val('hi')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea ></textarea>
```

Comment: @HazratBilal try with `result = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: @Parse - I think you didn't get my point...bcz the data comes in ' result[0].jobdescription ' correctly but my point is how to append it to texteditor.

Comment: @HazratBilal append means add with in previous text  in textarea.or just add text to textarea like the snippet answer

Comment: @Parse - for both.

Comment: @HazratBilal  `$('#edit_notes').val($('#edit_notes').val()+result[0].jobdescription);` ok lets  try this